# TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']

Tags: input, typeerror, require, encoder

I am working on classification problem where my dataset has categorical and numerical columns.

I tried to make Label encoding for categorical features

```
# Label encoding for categorical features
encoder = LabelEncoder()
categorical_features = ['employment_type', 'experience_level', 
                        'employee_residence', 'remote_ratio', 'company_location', 'company_size']
for feature in categorical_features:
    data[feature] = encoder.fit_transform(data[feature])
# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X = data.drop(["adjusted_salary", "salary_range"], axis=1)
y = data["salary_range"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Error is here:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in _unique_python(values, return_inverse, return_counts)
    172 
--> 173         uniques = sorted(uniques_set)
    174         uniques.extend(missing_values.to_list())

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in _unique_python(values, return_inverse, return_counts)
    176     except TypeError:
    177         types = sorted(t.__qualname__ for t in set(type(v) for v in values))
--> 178         raise TypeError(
    179             "Encoders require their input to be uniformly "
    180             f"strings or numbers. Got {types}"

TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']
```